# If constants are immutable, why can I reassign them using let?

Tags: ios, swift, constants, immutability

From the Apple docs "[Learn the Essentials of Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH3-SW1)"

> A constant is a value that stays the same after it’s declared the
>   first time, while a variable is a value that can change. A constant is
>   referred to as immutable, meaning that it can’t be changed, and a
>   variable is mutable. If you know that a value won’t need to be changed
>   in your code, declare it as a constant instead of a variable.

Yet in the REPL, I can do this:

```
 14> let favoriteNumber = 4
favoriteNumber: Int = 4
 15> let favoriteNumber = 5
favoriteNumber: Int = 5
```

I am clearly missing something: does this discrepancy have to do with the compiler or runtime, or is it something else?

[image]

Comment: I would put money on the fact that you can't do that. Because you can't. Lol. Can you show a screenshot of that code.

Comment: @fogmeister there it is

Comment: oh, in that. I thought you meant in a playground. Like has been said below. In this you are not changing the value of anything. You are creating a new constant that happens to have the same name. Try changing it, it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see how this gives the impression you are changing the value of a constant, but in actuality you aren't changing the value of favoriteNumber. What is happening is you are declaring a new constant with the same identifier as the previous declaration. In essence this hides the first declaration and it is if only the second favoriteNumber exists. If you try the following:

```
let favoriteNumber = 4
favoriteNumber = 5
```

You will see that you are not allowed to change the value of a constant.

It would probably be helpful if the REPL produced a warning that you redeclared an existing constant or variable.

Comment: sorry didn't understand this sentence 
"In essence this hides the first declaration and it is if only the second favoriteNumber exists."

Comment: You are right, this makes a completel sense for REPL.

Comment: A simplified explanation is the compiler uses the identifiers you create, in this case favoriteNumber, to refer to an address in memory. For example, when you have your first let favoriteNumber  = 4, the compiler uses favoriteNumber to refer to an address in memory, and at that address is the value 4. When you entered let favoriteNumber = 5, the compiler uses another address in memory and there places the value 5. The first address is "hidden" because favoriteNumber now refers to the second address, and you don't have an identifier that corresponds to the first address.

Answer (score 5):

You can do things in the REPL that you can't do in normal code.

You can't re-assign constants in a playground or in compiled code.

I am not sure if this is a special convenience offered in the REPL, or a bug.

Comment: Apparently, you can *redeclare* constants within the same scope [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63345436/13426627)

Answer (score 0):

## This is not allowed

Reassigning constants is not allowed.
As of Swift 5.2, it is advertised that you cannot redeclare them either (or at least, make invalid redeclarations of such within the same scope):

```swift
let this = true
let this = false
// Compiler Error: Invalid redeclaration if 'this'
```

---

In the REPL you are probably allowed to *redeclare* values. I'm pretty sure because of the following:

---

## But secretly, it is

Apparently, you don't need the REPL to *redeclare* values.

I accidentally discovered that you can do this, and it will compile:

```swift
let this = true
guard case let this = 100 else {}
print(this) // 1
```

It's cool that you can even redeclare a value to a different type.

Since we are only [`hid[ing] the first declaration`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32341560/13426627), this is allowed.